# Enum forward declaration vs. header files

Tags: c++, enums, forward-declaration

In the LearnCPP CH4.5 Enumerated Types, it states

> Because the compiler needs to know how much memory to allocate for an enumeration, you cannot forward declare enum types. However, there is an easy workaround. Because defining an enumeration does not allocate any memory, if an enumeration is needed in multiple files, it is fine to define the enumeration in a header, and #include that header wherever needed.

I thought header files are collection of forward declarations but just in a separate file. Then why would declaring an enumeration type in the header file any different as forward declaring in the same file that it is being used?

Comment: In this case there is no enum "forward declaration". Rather the same definition is *shared* between all source files which include said header.

Comment: "forward declaration" is not official terminology. It is saying that you can *define* an enum in the header .  It's no different to defining it in the cpp file, but helps to avoid errors like defining the same enum differently in different files

Answer (score 3):

The statement here is not really about where the enumeration is declared, it is about the difference between a declaration and a definition.

Something like

```
enum MyEnum; // just a declaration, not a definition

struct Foo {
    MyEnum value;
};
```

fails to compile because the compiler can't determine the size of `MyEnum` just from the declaration, but needs that size to determine the size of the struct `Foo` defined in the snippet above.

This is in contrast to something like

```
// the following is both a declaration and a defintion of the enum `MyEnum`
enum MyEnum {
    your,
    enumerators,
    go,
    here
};

struct Foo {
  MyEnum value;
};
```

which compiles because the compiler now has all required information to determine the size of struct `Foo`.

However, the source you quoted seems to be a little outdated. Since C++11 the declaration of an enum can suffice as long as its size is known, i.e. because you either explicitly specify the underlying type of an unscoped enum (e.g. `enum MyEnum : unsigned int;`) or because you use a scoped enum, which by default uses `int` as its underlying type. That is

```
enum MyEnum : int; // declaration only, but with specified underlying type
enum class Bar;  // also only declaration, `int` is implicit underlying type

struct Foo {
    MyEnum v1;
    Bar v2;
};
```

compiles just fine.